# Why does importing a Python class instantiate it?

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

A somewhat cut down example here from some PyTest unit tests that never exit. If I stick a break point on `DataListener.__init__` I see it getting called from the `from controller import Controller` statement in `test_controller.py` which was a bit of a suprise to me; Why does importing a class from a module instantiate an instance of it?

### data_listener.py

```
class DataListener:

    def __init__(self, port, host='localhost'):
        self._stop_monitor = Event()
        self._monitor = Thread(target=self.check_last_message)
        self._monitor.start()

    def __del__(self):
        self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_monitor.set()
        self._monitor.join()

    def check_last_message(self):
        while not self._stop_monitor.is_set():
            # Code to check for a heartbeat here
            pass
```

### controller.py

```
from data_listener import DataListener

class Controller:
    def __init__(
        self,
        subscriber=DataListener(port=DEFAULT_SUBSCRIBER_PORT),
        publisher=JsonPublisher(DEFAULT_PUBLISHER_PORT)):

        pass
```

### test_controller.py

```
from controller import Controller

def test_controller_work_loop():
    # ARRANGE
    controller = Controller(subscriber=None, publisher=None)

    # Some actual tests here
    # This test passes and finishes but the test suite never exits
```

Comment: Default arguments are evaluated immediately. Try running the code `def func(x=print("hi")):`

Comment: Sorry about the first comment - I simply misread the code. @Gaberocksall is correct, and this is a common issue explained by one of the most frequently-cited duplicates in the Python tag. A good debugger should allow you to step into the `import` and see that the `class` statement itself is executed (to create a function object representing the `__init__` method).

Comment: "Why does importing a class from a module instantiate an instance of it?" - well, no, that isn't what's happening at all. First off, you can't actually import "a class from a module" - the `from` syntax means that the module is imported, and than the class is bound to a name in the current module. Second, you imported `controller`, but it's a `DataListener` being instantiated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default arguments are evaluated when the class is loaded.

```
from data_listener import DataListener

class Controller:
    def __init__(
        self,
        subscriber=DataListener(port=DEFAULT_SUBSCRIBER_PORT),  # These are run!
        publisher=JsonPublisher(DEFAULT_PUBLISHER_PORT)):

        pass
```

You need to update your `Controller` class to initialize them lazily in your initializer

```
from data_listener import DataListener

class Controller:
    def __init__(self, subscriber=None, publisher=None):
        self.subscriber = subscriber or DataListener(port=DEFAULT_SUBSCRIBER_PORT)
        self.publisher = publisher or JsonPublisher(DEFAULT_PUBLISHER_PORT)
```